# How to use LIB file in C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries

There is a `lib` file along with `.h`, which is working with some device driver.
A sample Visual Studio C++ project is using that library as static linked.

There are only 2 functions exported from that library.

```
HANDLE open_dev();
HANDLE open_file( char *filename );
```

I want to use that library in my C# project and again static link it. How it's possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to static link to it. But you can make a c++ DLL and export the functions you need.

Comment: @Wimmel how to convert that lib easily into DLL, suitable for C#?

Comment: @Pablo about dll creation in VS [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx). Any dll is suitable for use in C# via P/Invoke.

Comment: @alexolut basically I have to create VS DLL project, which will act as wrapper? declare new export functions and call the ones from `lib`?

Comment: @Pablo yes. Result dll will contain the whole of .lib code inside. If you have dll, you don't need .lib anymore for using from C#.

Comment: I was hoping to have no additional files like DLL, but if not possible then I have no choice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a DLL where you create a wrapper function for each function from the .lib:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) HANDLE OpenFile(char const * filename)
{
    return open_file(filename);
}
```

In C# you use P/Invoke to make the dll function available:

```
[DllImport("WrapperLib.dll")]
private static extern System.IntPtr OpenFile(string filename);
```

Comment: `A call to PInvoke function 'xxx::OpenFile' has unbalanced the stack...`

Comment: nevermind, figured out I had to use `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in DllImport

Comment: @Pablo it can occure when wrong calling convention used. See respective settings for DllImport attribute.